# How can I find the JSON error in my DialogFlow request?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

I am sending the following intent creation json to [DialogFlow API hook](https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/) and keep getting the error "JSON syntax error". Is there a way I can get a more detailed description of the error?

```
{
"templates": [],
"lastUpdate": 1508084934,
"fallbackIntent": "false",
"name": "address-intent",
"contexts": [
    "order-intent-order-done-confirm-followup"
],
"auto": "true",
"webhookUsed": "true",
"events": [],
"priority": 500000,
"userSays": [
    {
        "count": 0,
        "isTemplate": "false",
        "data": [
            {
                "text": "deliver to ",
                "userDefined": "false"
            },
            {
                "text": "washington square",
                "meta": "@sys.address",
                "userDefined": "false",
                "alias": "address"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "isTemplate": "false",
        "data": [
            {
                "text": "please deliver it to ",
                "userDefined": "false"
            },
            {
                "text": "washington square",
                "meta": "@sys.address",
                "userDefined": "false",
                "alias": "address"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "isTemplate": "false",
        "data": [
            {
                "text": "34 1st street",
                "meta": "@sys.address",
                "userDefined": "false",
                "alias": "address"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "isTemplate": "false",
        "data": [
            {
                "text": "deliver it to ",
                "userDefined": "false"
            },
            {
                "text": "washington square",
                "meta": "@sys.address",
                "userDefined": "false",
                "alias": "address"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"webhookForSlotFilling": "false",
"responses": [
    {
        "affectedContexts": [
            {
                "name": "address-intent-followup",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 1
            }
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "address",
                "dataType": "@sys.address",
                "required": "true",
                "value": "$address",
                "prompts": [
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "value": "What's the address for the delivery?"
                    },
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "value": "Where should we send the order to?"
                    },
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "value": "What's your address?"
                    }
                ],
                "isList": "false"
            }
        ],
        "messages": [
            {
                "lang": "en",
                "speech": [],
                "type": 0
            }
        ],
        "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
        "action": "address-intent",
        "speech": [],
        "resetContexts": "false"
    }
]
}
```

To be clear, other intent creation requests work (as well as get requests) so I am pretty sure something in my JSON is wrong. The JSON is a valid JSON (validated [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/))

Comment: JSON is indeed valid, check the manual, maybe the the format needs to be provided as string, or wrapped with quotes.

Comment: The problem is probably not with the format since other requests (with different content) work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the  `prompts` collection.
It should have been a list of strings and not of objects.
A decent error message would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you've provided is the JSON that Dialogflow will send to your webhook in the body of the request to your webhook.  To respond to your users you must respond to this request with a response that looks like this:

```
Headers:
Content-type: application/json

Body:
{
"speech": "Barack Hussein Obama II was the 44th and current President of the United States.",
"displayText": "Barack Hussein Obama II was the 44th and current President of the United States, and the first African American to hold the office. Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, Obama is a graduate of Columbia University   and Harvard Law School, where ",
"data": {...},
"contextOut": [...],
"source": "..."
}
```

the `data`, `contextOut` and `source` attributes are optional.  `speech` and `displayText` are required and correspond to what is spoken and displayed to the user respectively.

Comment: This json is sent to the post handler of the intents endpoint - meaning it creates a new intent.